# Time diff in Ruby in terms of minute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, datetime, rubygems

I am working on datediff in Ruby. I am making a query to the datebase and I am getting createdDate result in this format:

```
2016-04-10T19:54:44.000Z.
```

My task is to check whether difference of createdDate and current time is greater than 30 mins or not. When I create current time in UTC format :

```
utctime = Time.now.utc
```

I am getting result like this ;

```
2016-04-10 19:59:57 UTC
```

My question is: the createdDate that I get from the database has T and .000Z. in it, it is any easy way to compare them to find 30 mins difference.

Because right now, I am planning to change:

T with space and .000Z. with UTC to make them in the same format.

Comment: What kind of database is that? The camel case name (`createdDate`) and its type (string?) are unusual. Furthermore, wouldn't it be much easier to use an ORM like Active Record?

Answer (score 2):

You can use standard `-` operator for `Time` objects:

```
time_diff = Time.parse('2016-04-10T19:54:44.000Z') - utctime #in seconds
result = (time_diff / 60).abs > 30 #true or false
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I want, but for the second part: I prefer to use : result = (parsed_time-utctime.to_i).abs.min

Comment: This is a component of Time. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_date_time.htm but I am not sure if it is correct usage since I am new in Ruby

Comment: @GökhanAkduğan, in this case it is not correct, `result` is a `Float` value

Comment: @GökhanAkduğan, same with `Integer`

Comment: how parse method realizes that I am dealing with UTC time?

Comment: @GökhanAkduğan "Z" means "UTC"